# Group by one column and see all unique results of another column of uneven lengths

Tags: r, group-by, unique

I want to create sort my dataframe by all unique sites and list all of the values in another column (without performing any function on those values). The values for each site will be of different lengths. I want to keep the values numerical so I can do some data manipulation afterwards (such as box plots among others).

I'm able to use tidyverse and create a string of uneven characters.

Sample data

```
a<-data.frame(c(41.14542,41.14542,41.14542,41.14542,41.14542), 
c(-74.1129,-74.1129,-74.1129,-74.1129,-74.1129), c(89,36,20,26,35))
colnames(a)<-c("LAT","LONG","value")
b<-data.frame(c(43.00309,43.00309,43.00309), 
c(-75.02384,-75.02384,-75.02384), c(1,17,20))
colnames(b)<-c("LAT","LONG","value")
c<-data.frame(c(43.17203,43.17203), c(-77.52824,-77.52824), c(2,2))
colnames(c)<-c("LAT","LONG","value")
samp_data<-rbind(a,b,c)
```

Code I've tried

```
library(tidyverse)
samp<-samp_data %>% group_by(LAT, LONG) %>%  mutate(value_string = paste(value, collapse = ",")) %>% select(LAT, LONG, value_string) %>% unique()
```

This gives me this result:

```
    LAT  LONG value_string   
    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>        
1  41.1 -74.1 89,36,20,26,35
2  43.0 -75.0 1,17,20       
3  43.2 -77.5 2,2
```

*I don't know why it's rounding my LAT/LONG values.

I need the third column to be numeric, not a string of characters. So something like this would work (note class of value_string):

```
    LAT  LONG value_string   
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>        
1  41.1 -74.1 89,36,20,26,35
2  43.0 -75.0 1,17,20       
3  43.2 -77.5 2,2
```

I've looked at aggregate (seems to require applying some function), playing with lists (having trouble with the uneven lengths for each site) but couldn't get them to work.

Also, I don't want to aggregate, i.e. site (43.17203,-77.52824) needs to appear twice and not be treated/combined as one row. So this wouldn't be ideal:

```
    LAT  LONG value_string   
    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>        
1  41.1 -74.1 89,36,20,26,35
2  43.0 -75.0 1,17,20       
3  43.2 -77.5 2
```

(row 3 with only one value instead of two values).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your expectation seems to be contradict themselves. You want unique site, while also mentioning 'do not want to aggregate'. Also what do you mean by 'i need third col to be numeric, not a string of char' while you want the variable to list all the values. Your approach is fine up till `select` statement.

Comment: HI @liuminzhao, Sorry about that. I've put a more detailed explanation of what I'm looking for. I just see that when you use aggregate, you have to use some function (ie mean, max) but I don't want that. I want the raw values of that value column without any summary statistics done. Is select the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can place the 'value' in a `list` with `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
out <- samp_data %>% 
          group_by(LAT, LONG) %>% 
          summarise(value = list(unique(value)))
out
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   LAT [3]
#    LAT  LONG value    
#  <dbl> <dbl> <list>   
#1  41.1 -74.1 <dbl [5]> #note the different length of the list column
#2  43.0 -75.0 <dbl [3]>
#3  43.2 -77.5 <dbl [1]>
```

We can get the boxplots with

```
out %>%
  unnest %>% 
  boxplot(value ~ LAT, data = ., main = "residuals by covariate",
        xlab = "LAT", ylab = "value")
```

-plot

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That allows me to make a boxplot for the next step. It's not as tidy making one row = one site but it seems to me that's not possible based on other help pages that I've read? Also, could you explain the logic in your last step? I don't quite understand using summarize with the list.

Comment: @Tammy After grouping by 'LAT', 'LONG', the `summarise` does it that i creates a summarised column as a `list`.  The `list` column can have different lengths for its elements.

Comment: thank you for explaining it. I don't think I understand R or programming well enough so this may be a silly question. Is it somehow possible to make column 3 a list class. So the data frame would have only one site to each row (a site wouldn't appear in more than one row), and column 3 would list all of the unique 'value' (similar to the dataframe with the character string that I've managed to write) but it's numerical values vs characters?

Comment: @Tammy It is exactly what the `summarise` is doing

Comment: Hi @akrun, I am SO sorry. Rerunning your code, I didn't apply your code correctly and it's not what I'm trying accomplish. This is the output of your code:  `1 89, 36, 20, 26, 35, 1, 17, 2`. I still want a dataframe with LAT, LONG, numeric values --- not all of the values summarized together

Comment: @Tammy The `summarise` create a `list` column.  If you extract the `value` column, you will understand that these are `unique` values for each group

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192535/discussion-between-tammy-and-akrun).

Comment: @Tammy If you need multiple data.frames in a `list`, use `split` `split(samp_data, samp_data[c("LAT", "LONG")], drop = TRUE)`

Comment: Can you instead put lists of different lengths inside a column of a dataframe?

Comment: @Tammy Based on your earlier comment, the `summarise` is creating exaclty a `list` column for each row of grouping variable

Comment: I'm now seeing what you're seeing and think I figured it out!! Before, I was just getting only a list for an output and not the result that you published above (which is helpful to see thank you for the edit). I had library(plyr) uploaded and library(dplyr) uploaded and by removing plyr and dplyr, and only uploading dplyr, I finally got a dataframe like yours. I think plyr is imported by other packages and when both packages are uploaded, there's some kind of conflict.

Comment: @Tammy The issue is because of masking of functions.  `plyr` have `summarise/mutate` and that masks the `dplyr` functions (summarise/mutate).  You can explicitly mention `%>% dplyr::summarise(`

Comment: That's very helpful and clarifies a lot of issues. Last question, is it at all possible to do something like this? `boxplot(out$LAT~out$value, main="residuals by covariate", xlab="LAT", ylab="value")`

Comment: @Tammy Do you need `boxplot` for each row of `out`?

Comment: Just one boxplot. All sites on X, values on Y basically.

Comment: @Tammy If you do `out %>%  mutate(v1 = map2(LAT, value, ~ boxplot(.y, .x, main = "residuals by covariate", xlab = "LAT", ylab = "value")))` get 3 plots for each `'LAT'

Comment: @Tammy if you need one boxplot `out %>% unnest %>% boxplot(value ~ LAT, data = ., main = "residuals by covariate", xlab = "LAT", ylab = "value")`

Comment: YES! This last code is exactly what I want and have spent hours (days) trying to do! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

One option is to `nest` those values to keep them numeric

```
library(dplyr)

temp <- samp_data %>%
          group_by(LAT, LONG) %>%
         tidyr::nest(value)
temp

#    LAT  LONG data            
#   <dbl> <dbl> <list>          
#1  41.1 -74.1 <tibble [5 × 1]>
#2  43.0 -75.0 <tibble [3 × 1]>
#3  43.2 -77.5 <tibble [2 × 1]>
```

This will have `data` column as list value and each of those have a numeric column called `value`.

```
str(temp$data)
#List of 3
# $ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':  5 obs. of  1 variable:
#  ..$ value: num [1:5] 89 36 20 26 35
# $ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  1 variable:
#  ..$ value: num [1:3] 1 17 20
# $ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':  2 obs. of  1 variable:
#  ..$ value: num [1:2] 2 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Is there a way to call column 'value' in a plot though? I was trying to make boxplots for all the data. I didn't want to do some sort of loop because I didn't want individual box plot for each unique site.

Comment: boxplot(temp$LAT~data(temp$data), main="LAT", xlab="value", ylab="residuals")     so for example, this doesn't work.

Comment: @Tammy if you don't want to plot them separate then why not `boxplot(LAT~value, samp_data, main="LAT", xlab="value", ylab="residuals")` '. Why do you need to summarise them?

Comment: Thanks @ Ronak! I've done other analysis beyond box plots (box plots was just a more immediate frustration) so I was trying to find a way to basically just use one tidy data frame while being able to run any numerical calculations.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `unique()` right after `group_by()`?

```
samp_data_unique = samp_data %>% 
  group_by(LAT, LONG) %>% 
  unique()
```

This worked for me. And output would look like this.

```
> samp_data_unique
# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   LAT, LONG [3]
    LAT  LONG value
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  41.1 -74.1    89
2  41.1 -74.1    36
3  41.1 -74.1    20
4  41.1 -74.1    26
5  41.1 -74.1    35
6  43.0 -75.0     1
7  43.0 -75.0    17
8  43.0 -75.0    20
9  43.2 -77.5     2
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Thanks! It lets me do my next step but it's not ideal since row #9 should have shown up twice.